# Dispatch Group not notifying?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have this identical code in another app and it works without fail, now in this app the dispatch group is not notifying and my handler isn't getting called?  I can't figure out the difference between the 2 apps since the code is identical?

```
 func getHeartRateMaxFromWorkouts(workouts: [HKWorkout], handler: @escaping (careerMaxHeartRatePerWorkoutAsCustomHistoricalSample, careerAverageHeartRatePerWorkoutAsCustomHistoricalSample) -> Void) {

        let workoutsReversed = workouts.reversed()
        guard let heartRateType:HKQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate) else { return }
        let heartRateUnit:HKUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
        var heartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample = [CustomHistoricalSample]()
        var heartRateAvgArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample = [CustomHistoricalSample]()

        //DispatchGroup needed since making async call per workout and need notified when all calls are done
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for workout in workoutsReversed {

            //predicate
            let startDate = workout.startDate
            let endDate = workout.endDate

            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

            //descriptor
            let sortDescriptors = [
                NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: true) //Changed this to false so that HRR and MCS would calculate, always check this if not getting these values
            ]
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            let heartRateQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRateType,
                                               predicate: predicate,
                                               limit: (HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
                                               sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors)
                { (query:HKSampleQuery, results:[HKSample]?, error:Error?) -> Void in

                    guard error == nil else { print("get heart rate error"); return }

                    guard let unwrappedResults = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else { print("get heart rate error"); return}

                    let heartRatesAsDouble = unwrappedResults.map {$0.quantity.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)}

                    guard let max = heartRatesAsDouble.max() else { return }

                    let maxAsCustomHistoricalSample = CustomHistoricalSample(value: max, date: workout.startDate)
                    heartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.append(maxAsCustomHistoricalSample)

                    let average = heartRatesAsDouble.average
                    let averageAsCustomHistoricalSample = CustomHistoricalSample(value: average, date: workout.startDate)
                    heartRateAvgArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.append(averageAsCustomHistoricalSample)

                    dispatchGroup.leave()

                }
            healthStore.execute(heartRateQuery)

        } //End of for workout loop

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

            //Need to sort by date since the dates come back jumbled 
            let sortedReversedHeartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSampple = heartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.sorted { $0.date > $1.date }.reversed() as [CustomHistoricalSample]

             let sortedReversedHeartRateAverageArrayAsCustomHistoricalSampple = heartRateAvgArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.sorted { $0.date > $1.date }.reversed() as [CustomHistoricalSample]
            print("handler called = \(sortedReversedHeartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSampple.count)")

            handler(sortedReversedHeartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSampple, sortedReversedHeartRateAverageArrayAsCustomHistoricalSampple)
        }



    } //End getHeartRateMaxFromWorkouts
```

Comment: I think you are not leaving the dispatch group when you got error in the completion block. Just leave the group in every error case.

Comment: When ever you can not go by the guard you should leave the group in the else block.

Comment: I dont think that's it because (1) none of the errors print in the console and (2) I put a breakpoint right above `dispatchgroup.leave` and hit it

Comment: And this **guard let max = heartRatesAsDouble.max() else { return }**

Comment: yep you were both right, was definitely not leaving in the error block, or as @Sh_Khan says just putting it at the top 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good practice to make leave top of callback

```
guard error == nil else { print("get heart rate error");  dispatchGroup.leave() return ; }

guard let unwrappedResults = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else { print("get heart rate error"); dispatchGroup.leave(); return}

let heartRatesAsDouble = unwrappedResults.map {$0.quantity.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)}

guard let max = heartRatesAsDouble.max() else { dispatchGroup.leave();  return }

let maxAsCustomHistoricalSample = CustomHistoricalSample(value: max, date: workout.startDate)

heartRateMaxArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.append(maxAsCustomHistoricalSample)

let average = heartRatesAsDouble.average

let averageAsCustomHistoricalSample = CustomHistoricalSample(value: average, date: workout.startDate)

dispatchGroup.leave()

heartRateAvgArrayAsCustomHistoricalSample.append(averageAsCustomHistoricalSample)
```

Comment: This is bad because the `notify` may be called before the rest of this block completes and the notify block may depend on this data.

Comment: Agree it's a little better practice just to leave in all the error blocks and also at the bottom (happy path)

Comment: @rmaddy I think this may harm the last response , but if error occurs then it'll not make difference as the result already isn't complete

Comment: Keep in mind that the answer in the duplicate is much better than this since it uses `defer` and avoids the need to clutter every `guard` with a call to `leave`.